# AT commands to send an SMS message over a CDMA Verizon phone

Tags: android, sms, desktop, at-command

I am trying to send an SMS command from a desktop application using a Samsung Galaxy s5 CDMA phone from Verizon.  I have tried using the GSM commands (AT+CMGS,etc) but I get an CMS:500 error.  Does anyone know if there are any other commands that might work or any other method of sending the SMS message with a CDMA phone.

Thanks
Gary

Comment: Can you post your code, and the full error copy and pasted?

Comment: Hi Noah, thanks for your response.  I checked with Samsung tech support today and they told me it is not possible with a CDMA network. Regards,Gary

Comment: Ok, good to know.

Comment: @Gary Please make an answer for your question (yes, it is fine and expected to answer your own questions when you find the answer later).

Answer (score 0):

According to Samsung tech support, it is not possible with a CDMA network using the Galaxy s5.

Regards,Gary